# How to change title and width of Datatables columnFilter plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables

how i can configure Datatables ColumnFilter plugin to customize the width of the input filter show at bottom of each column ?

I need to change the placeholder shown in each input box. I don't want that is shown the name of the data field, but i want to show a custom string.

Is it possible via the Columnfilter or Datatable configuration ?

Thanks in advance,
Giuseppe.

Answer (score 1):

Well, have you ever studied the code? It is very easy to change. The placeholders are simply the content given in the required `<tfoot>` sections.
If we look at the classic [**ColumnFilter demo**](http://jquery-datatables-column-filter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/index.html), the structure is :

```html
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Rendering engine</th>
        <th>Browser</th>
        <th>Platform(s)</th>
        <th>Engine version</th>
        <th>CSS grade</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

change that to for example :

```html
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>Enter engine name</th>
        <th>Enter browser name</th>
        <th>Enter platform</th>
        <th>Enter engine version</th>
        <th>Enter CSS grade</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/pbu5xfyp/**

---

There is no option for styling the individual inputs generated by ColumnFilter. This must be done by "hand" in CSS; imho the far easiest way to do this is (example) :

```css
tfoot th:nth-child(1) input {
    width: 40px;
}
tfoot th:nth-child(2) input {
    width: 240px;
    background-color: #ebebeb;
}
tfoot th:nth-child(3) input {
    width: 100px;
    color: red;
}
```

etc, demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/3uqvwofo/**

Comment: Hi davidkonrad, thanks for reply. Well for the placeholder, but how i can specify the witdh of the input filter ? At the moment i use an additional css to do it, thw property Width of the columnFilter seem not work. I wrong something ?

Comment: @user783244 No - you are right, there is no option in columnFilters' `aoColumns` to specify the width or any other visual layout.  You must use additional CSS, see updated answer.